# nyroModal close button problem in chrome using jquery 1.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal

When I open nyroModal in Chrome and resize the window the closeButton fails to reposition to the new dimensions instead remaining fixed to its original position. I have tested this problem and found that it is being caused by jquery 1.6, my site has been written using 1.6 so Im not sure I can drop down. Has anyone any suggestions on what I can do to make nyro work with 1.6?

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: can you put together a demo of the issue that you are seeing, say on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/xUnXr/ (note that that example is using jQuery 1.6.2).

The simplest **solution** is to **update jQuery to 1.6.3**. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xUnXr/1/